# How do I access JSON data from a JSON file I receive via HTTP request in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest

```
var http = require('http');

var optionsget = {
    host : 'demo4712411.mockable.io',
    port : 80,
    path : '/Jobs',
    method : 'GET'
};


console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsget);
console.info('Do the GET call');

var reqGet = http.get(optionsget, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
    console.log("------- ID " + res.Lat);

    var buffer='';

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        buffer += d.toString();
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        console.info('GET result:\n');
        console.log(buffer);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error("Error: --" + e);
});

reqGet.end();
```

So I am getting all the output I need, and I do get the JSON file as a string --

GET result:

```
{
    "Id" : 23
    "OwnerrId" : 233
    "ProviderId" : 2343
    "Lat" : 342.23423
    "Long" : 23.32233
    "Address" : "234 Maybach way, Bellevue 98803"
}
```

However, I am having trouble accessing the components of the JSON File (like Id, and OwnerrId). I have tried a couple things like JSON.parse(d), but that gives me an error. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Your JSON response is not correct. Add comma between each property: { "Id" : 23, "OwnerrId" : 233, "ProviderId" : 2343, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you an error because it isn't JSON. The commas between each key: value pair are missing.

Either fix the server you are requesting the data from so it returns real JSON or write a custom parser for the non-standard format.

Comment: Thanks! Always miss out on the simple things.